# Calculated field on from date

Tags: archer

Can anyone please let me know how to use date as calculated filed.
Eg: I created a field "from date" in my new application, I want to make this as calculated field. I want to use formula - "from date field should not be less than todays date"
How can I achieve it.

I entered below formula
[From Date]>=TODAY()
It gives error in front end application

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve.   If you're making it calculated there's no need to check if it's less than the current date.  If you're look to set the date in the future use the DATEADD() function.

Answer (score 0):

From date is always going to be less than Today, if I am not wrong. It may be equal but never greater than today right? If you want to use the way you have in the formula then you can use `DATEDIF(Start_date, End_date, Unit)`

You can check this link:
https://help.archerirm.cloud/platform_613/en-us/content/platform/calcfunctions/date_functions.htm#DATEDIFFunction